# Regex: Check that file contains a line three times

Tags: regex, bash

How can I check with a regex that a file contains the same line "this is 123" (with indentation) exact three times?

File:

```
<dev>
  <source file='/path/to/file'/>
  <string>this is 123</string>
</dev>

<dev>
  <source dev='this dev'/>
  <string>this is 123</string>
</dev>

<dev>
  <source dev='another dev'/>
  <string>this is 123</string>
</dev>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use awk to count the lines

```sh
awk '/  <string>this is 123</string>/ { count++ } END { print count }' file.txt
```

the string to use is enclosed in `/`s.
After every line that awk encounters it increments a `count` and when it reaches the END it prints the count

use that count to compare in a conditional

```sh
c=$(awk '/  <string>this is 123</string>/ { count++ } END { print count }' file.txt)
if [[ c -eq 3 ]]; then
    # do stuff
fi
```